# What actually happened to Jacob's and Laban's sheeps and goats?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, animals, color, vayeitzei

Genesis 30 (JPS):

> 34 And Laban said: 'Behold, would it might be according to thy word.' 35 And he removed that day the he-goats that were streaked and spotted, and all the she-goats that were speckled and spotted, every one that had white in it, and all the dark ones among the sheep, and gave them into the hand of his sons. 36 And he set three days' journey betwixt himself and Jacob. And Jacob fed the rest of Laban's flocks. 37 And Jacob took him rods of fresh poplar, and of the almond and of the plane-tree; and peeled white streaks in them, making the white appear which was in the rods. 38 And he set the rods which he had peeled over against the flocks in the gutters in the watering-troughs where the flocks came to drink; and they conceived when they came to drink. 39 And the flocks conceived at the sight of the rods, and the flocks brought forth streaked, speckled, and spotted.

1. Jacob got all the black goats.
2. Laban hide all the black and spotted goats (verse 36)
3. So Jacob started off with pure white goats (or sheep?)
4. Jacob's technique turn the newborn goats spotted
5. Is the term for goats similar to sheep?

Let me try to understand

Do I get this right? Am I missing something?

Also what actually happened in the end anyway? All the goats become spotted (and hence belong to Jacob's) or Jacob's got stronger goats?

Looks like pure white goats is recessive and hence, normally 2 out of 4 goats born from carrier of black genes will be spotted.

My guess is it's not really miracle. What the goats see affect their sexual selection preference. That sexual selection affect which male impregnate the ewe and that affects the color of the child. That is why Jacob shows the branch only in front of strong males. I am just trying to get the detail right. It's amazing how Jacob could figure this out thousands of years ago before Richard Dawkins.

So the question is about the detail of the story:

1. In the deal, what kind of goats Jacob should get (spotted? pure?)
2. Did jacob put the branches in front of the male or female goats?
3. Did Jacob put the branch only in front of the strong goats or all goats?
4. What's the starting of condition?
5. Could an animal behaviorist verify the plausibility of the whole things.

Comment: My guess is it's not really  miracle. What the goats see affect their sexual selection preference. That sexual selection affect which male knock up the ewe and that affects the color of the child. That is why Jacob shows the branch only in front of strong males. I am just trying to get the detail right. It's amazing how Jacob could figure this out thousands of years ago before Richard Dawkins.

Comment: I think people have tried this experiment and it didn't work. The bible isn't a science book, but Jacob had to "do something" to inspire the miracle to be brought about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flock" in Hebrew means both sheep and goats; there are both sheep and goats here.

The deal was that Jacob was handed a bunch of white sheep and goats, and told that he'd get to keep any colored/patterned offspring. (Most likely this was some sort of recessive trait, so this was the equivalent of tossing coins.) By whatever working physical or metaphysical, a large number of the offspring (and this was repeated for several generations) were colored or patterned, so Jacob got to keep them. It also seems that Jacob employed some breeding technique to favor his getting the stronger or better-breeding animals.

So Jacob has a bunch of white sheep that are producing spotted offspring. He has a dream in which an angel says "look, here are spotted sheep mating."  Most likely what he's seeing is a representation of the recessive (spotty) genes within the white sheep getting picked.

Comment: "'Flock' in Hebrew means both sheep and goats; there are both sheep and goats here."  Also worth noting is the fact that the Hebrew word for "sheep" is often used to refer to goats as well; it is almost as if they are seen as an interchangeable species.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I a looking for. Could use even more detail though.

Answer (score 5):

The Madregas Haadam by the alter of Novardok, quotes the Ramban as saying that Yakov was at such a high level of trust in G-d, that it was as if "reality/natural order" did not exist. And therefore when a person is at such a level, there is no reason for the facade of nature. And therefore G-d changed the colors/patterns of the animals, even after they had been born! 
The only reason Yakov needed the sticks at all, was not so that the right colors/patterns would give birth, but rather that he was obligated to watch out for the wellbeing of the herd for Lavan, in that he had accepted a gaurdianship position which has legal obligations, and as such when lavan had removed parts of the flock, the sex drive of the animals was lowered and hence the colored sticks to increase drive. But the selection of colors and stripes  was 100% a miracle/result of the total Bitachon in G-d.

page 154-157 madreigas haadam
 אעפ״י שמדרגת
 יעקב כבטחון היתה. כ״כ גבוה, עד שכל המבע היתד• םשעובדת לו
 כמו שיאות ליעקב, ולא היה כיכלתו של לבן עם כל רמאותיו ל^סיד
 ליעקב כלום, וכל ההשתדלות של לבן עלתה בתוהו ולא פעלה כלל,
 ואף שהיה טצד הטבע סיוע ללבן, אבל מכיון שנם הטבע הי׳ נכנע
 להתהפך כפי טובת יעקב, לכן לא עלתה בידו כלל יגיעתו, אף שמצד
 הטבע היתה סיוע לו. והגה מבואר כתורה שהחליף את משכורתו
 עשרת םוגים, והיתה זה מרטאות של לבן, אחר שפסק עטו על עקודים,
 לשנות משכורהו אחר שנתערבו לנקודים, מאחר שחשב לבן שהרי
 בודאי היי העבור מעקודים לטובת יעקב הי׳ מתנכל לשנות מכפי
 מה שפסק בתחילה, לנקודיט, ובדעתו שפט שכיון שנתעברו עקודים
 שוב לא יתחלפו לנקודים ואחר שישנה עכשיו לנקודים, בטח הוא
 ירויה ולא יעקב. אטנם, באטת הי׳ םתחלף נם הטבע של הצאן, לפי
 התחלפות הפסק, והיו טתחלפים גם אחר העבור טעקודים לנקודים,
 עד• שכטו״כ גם בשעת הלידה, ואחר שראה לבן שגם הלידה הוא לטובת
 יעקב, הי׳ טחליף פסיקתו הקודטת, גם בשעת לידה לטובתו, וגם
  אז התחפר הטבע לפי פסיקתו העכשוית,׳ כטו שטבואר ברטב״ן עלהפסוק ״ויהי כאשר, ילדה הצאן׳/ שגם בשעת לידה נתהפך הצבע.של
 הצאן למובת יעקב. ,-. - •
 הרי נתברר לגו מזה: עד כמה הגיע. מדרגת בטחונו, עד שהי׳
 חזק ב״כ בדעתו וסמיכת לבו על ה׳, עד שאף שהחליף. לבן משכורתו
 עשרת מוגים, וגם בשעת לידה, והוא ידע בונת לבן, שלבן מחליף
 משכורתו מכפי שהיתה קודם, שסובר. שאחר העבור או בשעת הלידה,
 אם יחליף לטובתו, שוב א״א עוד שתשגה הצבע לטובת. יעקב, בכל
 זאת•הי׳ מסכים להפסק של לבן, והי׳ חזק בבטחוגו שלא יפסיד כלום,
 ושאין הצבע נחשב לגמרי שיגיע לו גזק או תועלת על ידה, אחר
 שהוא בומח בה׳, והי׳ תקיף בדעת שהבמחון בה׳ יכריע הכל לטובתו
 ולא התפעל כלום. אף אם החליף משכרתו עשרת מונים מגודל מדרגתו
 במדת הבמחון. ויתכן שזהו מה שרמזו חז״ל במאמרם ויאמר אלי
 מלאך האלקים בחלום יעקב, לו ולדורות, שאין •לך דור שאין בו
 כיעקב, רצו בזה ללמדנו שבאמת ביכולת כל אדם להגיע למדרגת
 הבטחון בלי שום סיבה כלל וכמו שהעלה הרמב״ן.
ומה שרבים שואלים — מאחר שיעקב היי שלם בתכלית השלימות
 במדרגת הבטחון ונעשו לו.נסים, מדוע הוצרך להמקלות, שלכאורה
 הוא סותר לגמרי לכל ענין הבטחון שאין לך סיבה גדולה.מהמקלות
 אשר יסבבו שיולידו הצאון ולדות כאלו שיהא בהם הצבעים לטובת
 יעקב. ומאחר שסוכ״ס החליף לבן את משכורתו הי׳ מתחלף הצבע
אחר
 לטובתו, הגם.שלא הי׳ אז שוס סיבה להתחלפות, כי כבר חי, 
 העיבור, ולפי דעת הרמב״ן אירע כזאת •גם בשעת לידה אשר אז
 בודאי אין מועיל שום סיבה טבעית לשנות הצבע לטובת יעקב. בכ״ז
 יש לתמוה לאיזה צורך העמיד המקלות כל עיקר,.והי׳ ראוי לפי שלמותו
 במדרגת הבטחון שלא יצטרך להמקלות כלל, שהוא דבר מותרי לגמרי
 להבומח באמת, ומה. הועילו לו המקלות מאהר שתוא גגד הבטחון
 לגמרי, ולא לבד שלא יועילו להבטחון עוד יביאו רפיון, לכאורה,
 בסמיכת לבו ובטחונו.
 אמנם זה מובן אף במושכל ראשון, שלא יתכן לאמר שפעולת
 המקלות היתד• מערמיםותו של יעקב לנרום לו טובה על לדם והוא
 השינע״י זה חפצו שיולידו הצאן לפי הראוי לטובתו, ולולא שמר
 המקלות חיה לבן מרויח ויעקב.נפסד דא״כ אי-ך לא. הכיר לבן את זאת
ונעשה ותרן ליעקב על ערמימות גדולח בזאת הלא מבואר שגם אחר
 שכבר קצץ ליעקב השכר שלו הי׳ חוזר ומחליף משכורתו גס אחר
 הפסק שלו, ואחר שהיה מבקש ומחזיר אחר כל ההתגכלות לרמות
 את יעקב ולגזול את משכורתו ממנו מכ׳׳ש שלא הי׳ מוותר העמדת
 המקלות אשר גלוי אצלו שיופסד על ידן, ומוכרחים לומר שלא העמדת
 המקלות באמת שוס סבה ליעקב שירויח על ידן, ולא פעלו כלל
 לטובתו, והוא מובן אף בתחילת העיון, שחרי בהמקלות היו הרבה
 צבעיט, ולא לבד הצבעיט טשכר של יעקב אלא גט טחצבעיט אשר היי
 טשכר של לבן ולכן לא גחשבו הטקלות בסוג בקשת סיבה בכטחונו
 ואף אם חיה בהטקלות סיבה להוליד הצאן שהוא טשכר יעקב, הרי
 לא הועילו כלום טאחר שגם אחר הפסק חי׳ טחליף לבן את טשכורתו,
 גטצא שא׳׳א שיהא בחם סיבה להוליד כפי טשכורותו, שלבן היי
 טשנח פסיקת טשכורתו פעטים חרבה ולא הי׳ אפשר ביד יעקב בעצטו
 לבחור בהצבעים שיולידו הצאן לטובתו, שהרי לבן שינה את טשכורתו
 נס אחר העיבור. אסנם, יקשה, א׳׳כ לאיזה ענין העטיד חטקלות
 וטח צורר בזח כל עיקר ?
 אכן ביאור חדבריט והוא הנכון: שצורר הטקלות היי בזח טצד
 שחיי ליעקב דין שוטר, והיי טחויב טצד דין חשטירה וחדין פועל
 לפקח בכל כוחו ותחבולתו לטובת בריאות ואפשרות הלידה לחצאן
 (עיין רמב׳׳ם סוף הלכות שכירות). ונמצא שכטו״כ הי׳ טחויב לחצינ
 את המקלות ליחמנה הצאן, כי בלתי החימום לא יצוייר העיבור
 ובהעדר הצבעים יחסר בה חימום כפי הצורך, וחיו המקלות אשר
 העמיד לתכלית זאת, אך ורק לסבב החמימות כפי הצורר, וכמו
 שהעידה התורה מפורש, ושם יעקב את המקלות לעיני הצאן ברהטים
 ליחמנה במקלות (ויצא לי).
אמנם צריכים להבין, מדוע התחיל להשתמש בחמקלות רק אחר
 שפסק לו לבן את שכרו ולא קודם, דאם הוא מהצורך לחמימות הצאן
 לסבב הלידה כפי הראוי הלא הי׳ מן הצורך שיעשה כמו׳׳כ קודם
 שקבע לו לבן שכרו כמו אח׳׳כ.
 אטנט הוא טבואר בפשיטות כי מקודם הלא לא הפריד לבן מהעדר
 כל טלוא ונקוד והי׳ בהעדר כל הצבעיט האלה והיו טתחטטיט טהעדר,
 כטבואר בתורה, לא אח״כ שהפריד לכן טהעדר כל שהנקוד וטלוא.
ז
מבעלדי
אי אפשר להמציא להצאן החמימות הראוי, 
 נמצא שאז הי, 
 המקלות לכן הי׳ מוכרח להשתמש בהמקלות במקום הצבעים שחיו
 בהעדר מקודם לכן, ונמצא שבודאי הי׳ הבטחון של יעקב בטחון שלמ
 בתכלית השלמות מבלי עזר.של נלנול הסיבות כלל. ובכל זאת הורנו
 חז״ל במאמרם ״ויאמר אלי יעקב אלי ולדורות אין לך דור שאין בו
 כיעקב״ היינו להאיר לנו הדרך שבאפשרות כל אחד ואחד אך אמ
 יש לו רצון חזק והוא בוטח על ח׳ באמת לעמוד בתמידות במדרנת
 הבמחון מבלי לבקש שוס עזר מסיבות כלל וכלל.

Answer (score 1):

What i remember when I studied this: since the goats were looking to a spotted piece of wood during the reproduction act, their childrens became spotted... so what you are thinking or feeling during the sex can influeciate in your childrens...dont know/remember exactly who said this...but I think is rashi

Comment: Rashi to 30:38 citing B'reishit Rabbah 73:10.

Comment: The thought that one's thoughts during or before sex will influence the appearance of the couple's children is alluded to, also, by Rabbi Yochanan quoted in the Babylonian Talmud, Bava Metzia 84a.

Comment: Your thought affect your preferences. Your preferences affect who you mate with. And that affect your child.

Comment: If your son watch enough japanese porn, 20 years latter you will really have japanese looking grand children. The same if your son watch too many blond porn. If your son read torah all days, chance is 20 years latter you'll have jewish grandchildren. That sort of thing. With goats the process is simpler because they have shorter life cycle than our species and much more simple minded.

Comment: If your son like blonds probably in the future he will marry a blond woman and bigger chances that you will have blond children. Hmmm...you cant know if your thoughts influence your child appearance or not.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. If your son like blonds then he will more likely marry blond and have bigger chance. So your thought doesn't influence your child appearance genetically (assuming the mate is the same), but change your child appearance behaviorally by making you mate with those you have in your mind more.

Answer (score -1):

as proven with humans ie: Moses hands  and the brazen serpent ,we know that auto suggestion can win a war or can cure even a snake bite, Regarding the strength of the goats /sheep and regarding the pigmentation , Jakob took both these into account , he used 3 types of wood the wood type had a specific purpose or reason ,
 both males and females drank at the troughs at different times and so the relevant messages were relayed to both genders , and even if that were not the case from the males alone information can be written into the seed

Comment: One important difference is that with Moshe's hands and the brass serpent, God said to do those things -- so it's reasonable to expect them to be effective.  Yaakov's animal-husbandry practices seem to be his own innovation.

Comment: The snake that bites israelites are most likely a specific kind of fiery worm